# Como uso o metodo sort para criar uma nova array ordenada sem alterar a principal

Tags: javascript

Ola tudo bom ? preciso usar o método sort() sem alterar a array principal, EX:

```
let clientes = [ 100, 80, 90]
let listaOrdenada = clientes

listaOrdenada.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a > b) return 1
    if (a < b) return -1
})
console.log(clientes)
console.log(listaOrdenada)
```

no caso preciso que a variável listaOrdenada seja igual a variável clientes só que em ordem decrescente, tentei varias formas, mas todas altera as duas variáveis.

A intenção é comparar as duas e ver quais os números que não precisou mudar de lugar  .

Comment: Em `let listaOrdenada = clientes` você não está clonando `clientes` e sim criando uma referência para ele. Você pode clonar utilizando o `let listaOrdenada = clientes.slice()`

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado !

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No JavaScript, objetos e arrays são passados por referência por padrão, ou seja, quando você aponta `y` para o array `x` você não está clonando `x` e sim se referindo a ele.

Neste caso, você pode clonar um array utilizando o `slice()`:

```js
let clientes = [ 100, 80, 90]
let listaOrdenada = clientes.slice()

listaOrdenada.sort(function(a,b) {
    if (a > b) return 1
    if (a < b) return -1
})
console.log(clientes)
console.log(listaOrdenada)
```

Comment: Resolvido, muito obrigado !

Comment: @GiovaneSantiago se essa resposta te ajudou, considere marcar ela como correta no botão abaixo das setas de voto.